# How to get tap:i18n to work with Meteor-Blaze?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Since there's not enough information in the doc on how to get the tap:i18n package up and running I had to ask because I did some googling to find some resources but with no luck.

So I did exactly as the official document says in "quickstart" section:

1. I added the package to my project
2. I added {{_ "hello"}} to one of my html pages
3. I created a folder in "impots\both" with the name "i18n"
4. I created a file with the name "en.i18n.json" containing:{ "hello": "Hey there" }

I tried to move the folder "i18n" that includes the json file but it didn't work.

This whole thing is giving an error while loading the page:

> Exception from Tracker recompute function:  meteor.js:930:11 Error: No
>   such function: _

What did I miss?

Comment: put the i18n folder not in imports/both but in top level of your project (or did you mean that with move?)

Regarding "No such function: _" - are you testing or running the app? Because in Testing Blaze Templates this is a common error when you dont register _ to the Blaze Root

Comment: @Jankapunkt yes I tried to move  "i18n" folder to the root of thr project but still the same problem. How am I supposed to register the _ template? I thought that what the package does!

Comment: "I thought that what the package does!" - Yes it dows that in your dev/prod environment but not in the testing environment - which is why I am asking: are you currently having this error on test or on dev?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I'm still in development

Comment: Okay I just checked your steps again, do you also implemented step four of the tap:i18n package quickstart, as statet in the documentation? See https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n#quickstart

Comment: @Jankapunkt it's mentioned that step 4 is optional. But I tried it anyway and it's not the answer unfortunately